# Unit Test Image Serialization

Tags: c#, image, unit-testing, serialization

I wasn't able to find an answer for this so hopefully someone can help me.  I am trying to use the following code to serialize and deserialize an image.

```
    public override string Serialize(Image image)
    {
        ImageFormat format = ImageFormat.Png;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }

    public override Image Deserialize(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            throw new Exception("Invalid serialized string. Unable to deserialize image");

        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);                        
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        {
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return image;
        }           
    }
```

From a visual test this code works as expected but I am unable to verify this through a unit test.  I am trying to use the the following code to compare the image, which I have been able to successfully unit test if the images are identical.

```
    public static bool IsEqualTo(this Image sourceImage, Image compareImage)
    {
        if (sourceImage.Size != compareImage.Size)
            return false;

        byte[] sourceHash = sourceImage.CreateHash();
        byte[] compareHash = compareImage.CreateHash();

        return sourceHash.IsEqualTo(compareHash);
    }

    private static byte[] CreateHash(this Image image)
    {
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] byteArray = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));

        SHA256Managed shaM = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hash = shaM.ComputeHash(byteArray);
        return hash;
    }

    private static bool IsEqualTo(this byte[] source, byte[] compare)
    {
        if (source.Length != compare.Length)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            if (source[i] != compare[i])
                return false;

        return true;
    }
```

With both of these parts completed I am trying to write a unit test that assumes that serialization occurred successfully and will simply validate that I continue to get the same serialized string.  The serialized string is then used to initialize a new image that I compare using the following code:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Deserialize_Success()
    {
        Image expected = this.LoadImage();
        string imageString = this.GetImageString();
        ImageSerializer serializer = new ImageSerializer();

        Image actual = serializer.Deserialize(imageString);

        bool match = expected.IsEqualTo(actual);
        Assert.True(match);
    }
```

If I save the image to the file system and perform a visual comparison it looks like everything worked as I would have expected but the unit test will fail.  The only thing that I can think of is that there is a small variance caused by the method that is used to load the image that is making it appear different.

Can anyone shed some light on how I might be able to successfully write a unit test for this?

Update:

I found the question [Weird behavior during Image byte array serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960947/weird-behavior-during-image-byte-array-serialization) which is similar.  I attempted to use the same image that they used from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Snow_flake_icon.png but I am seeing differences even with this.  Using this question as I guide I took a closer look at the byte arrays that are being created.

The first major difference is that in the image that is deserialized we the first thirteen bytes are not present.  There are additional variances with 29 additional bytes with all of the variances being in the first 46 bytes.  My issue is that I don't think that I can assume there will always be a 13 byte offset for images that are deserialized and that I can just ignore the first 46 bytes.

The full details are:

```
Expected Length: 17932  Actual Length: 17919

expected[0]=137         Actual Not Present
expected[1]=80          Actual Not Present
expected[2]=78          Actual Not Present
expected[3]=71          Actual Not Present
expected[4]=13          Actual Not Present
expected[5]=10          Actual Not Present
expected[6]=26          Actual Not Present
expected[7]=10          Actual Not Present
expected[8]=0           Actual Not Present
expected[9]=0           Actual Not Present
expected[10]=0          Actual Not Present
expected[11]=13         Actual Not Present
expected[12]=73         Actual Not Present
expected[13]=72         actual[13]=72
expected[14]=68         actual[14]=68
expected[15]=82         actual[15]=82
expected[16]=0          actual[16]=0
expected[17]=0          actual[17]=0
expected[18]=1          actual[18]=1
expected[19]=0          actual[19]=0
expected[20]=0          actual[20]=0
expected[22]=1          actual[22]=1
expected[24]=8          actual[24]=8
expected[25]=6          actual[25]=6
expected[26]=0          actual[26]=0
expected[27]=0          actual[27]=0
expected[28]=0          actual[28]=0
expected[29]=92         actual[29]=92
expected[30]=114        actual[30]=114
expected[31]=168        actual[31]=168
expected[32]=102        actual[32]=102
expected[35]=0          actual[35]=0
expected[36]=1          actual[36]=4
expected[37]=115        actual[37]=103
expected[38]=82         actual[38]=65
expected[39]=71         actual[39]=77
expected[40]=66         actual[40]=65
expected[42]=174        actual[42]=0
expected[43]=206        actual[43]=177
expected[44]=28         actual[44]=143
expected[45]=233        actual[45]=11
```

Comment: The first 8 of those missing bytes is the PNG header, the remaining 5 probably also part of the image header. I think the use of ImageConverter looks suspicious. Can't you just save the image to a memory stream to get the byte data from it?

Comment: @AndersForsgren The ImageConverter is only being used to create the hash to determine if the images match and not for serialization.  The byte comparison was made using the actual bytes of the source image and deserialized image using a MemoryStream.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `ImageConverter` I think you test too much of the internal representation of images in .NET, rather than the images being "equal" in some sense. I'm not sure what a

To convert an image to a byte array I'd use

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    im.Save(ms);
    byteArr = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Just like you are doing in the serialize method. The byte arrays in your example are missing the PNG header in the second case, so something is definitely causing it to dump a PNG file in one case, and something completely different in the other. Why ImageConverter behaves like this I don't know. But the fact that `Load` and `Save` do not give identical in-memory Image objects is a clue:

When you load this particular file from disk, serialize to base64 and then load again, there are differences in metadata.

```
var im1 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Snow_flake_icon.png");
string s1 = Serialize(im1);
var im2 = Deserialize(s1);
string s2 = Serialize(im2);

bool equalBase64 = s1 == s2; // true
```

We can see that re-serializing the deserialized image in this case gives the same base64 string (but I wouldn't count on that given the reasons below).

If you look at the objects `im1` and `im2` above in a watch window you'll see that there are differences however. Metadata will differ when the file is loaded from the byte64 stream compared to when it is loaded directly from file.

The metadata of im1 (Found in the `PropertyItem` property of the images):

```
0x5110 (PixelUnit)          
0x5111 (Pixels per unit X) 
0x5112 (Pixels per unit Y)
```

The image im2 loaded from the base64 string has these properties:

```
0x5110 (PixelUnit)           
0x5111 (Pixels per unit X)   
0x5112 (Pixels per unit Y)   
0x0303 (sRGBRenderingIntent) 
0x0301 (Gamma)
```

So a `Load`/`Save` pair is not necessarily symmetric even for a lossless format like PNG or BMP, and using ImageConverter to convert to byte array appears to be even less reliable. I would expect there to exist at least one serialize method in the framework (BinaryFormatter, ImageConverter, Image.Save...) that serializes the complete internal state of the Image object which is not what you want.

If you want to compare the image data I recommend you cast the image to a `Bitmap`, then use  `LockBits` to get the pixel data, and then hash that. Even in this case you must keep in mind that an identical image must not necessarily have an identical binary representation of the pixels, a 100% transparent pixel can have several rgba representations.